# Fluentbit: How to have Kubernetes filter working with cpu input

Tags: kubernetes, fluent-bit

Does Fluentbit Kubernetes FILTER compatible with cpu and mem INPUT?

I fail to configure cpu and mem INPUT with kubernetes filter.
It's okay with tail INPUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes Filter depends on either **and only** from Tail or Systemd input plugins to process and enrich records with Kubernetes metadata.

This is documented here:
https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit-docs/blob/master/filter/kubernetes.md#workflow-of-tail--kubernetes-filter